# How to find what resources are members of a security group via boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm trying to find out what resources (EC2, RDS, LB, EFS etc.) are associated with a particular security group.

I can filter `describe_ec2_instances()` with `group-name` or `group-id`, but can't see that functionality with `describe_rds_instances()` or same for LB, EFS. I tried using `describe_network_interfaces()` filtered by group, and whilst I can see that a particular interface is used by RDS, EFS or whatever, I can't see an `instanceId` to relate back to the actual resource.